# Equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z$ with the operation $\mod n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

So I came across this phrase in my abstract algebra textbook:

> The integers $\mod n$ also partition $\Bbb Z$ into $n$ different equivalence classes; we will denote the set of these equivalence classes $\Bbb Z_n$. For example, for integers modulo 12,  $\Bbb Z_0 = \lbrace ..., -12, 0, 12, 24, ...\rbrace$ and $\Bbb Z_2 = \lbrace ..., -10, 2, 14, 26, ...\rbrace$

I am trying to trace it back to the original $X$ set, i.e. if the definition of an equivalence class is $$[x] = \lbrace y \in X; y \sim x \rbrace$$ provided $x \in X$, what is the $X$ in this case?

Comment: Be careful, $\Bbb Z_0$ wouldn't be the thing you're saying it is under your definition! $\{...,-12,0,12,24,...\}$ is the class of $0$, which is an element of $\Bbb Z_{12}$.

Comment: @SolidSnake Sorry, forgot to mention $n \in [0, 11]$

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem! the question is the following: Is $\Bbb Z_n$ a set that contains WHAT kind of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{Z}$ and a natural number $n$. Your book says that the set of all natural numbers can be divided into $n$ different equivalent classes. Indeed, all these classes are denoted as $[0]_n,[1]_n,...,[n-1]_n$.

Now to answer your question, consider some equivalent class $[3]_n$ for example. Let us remind ourselves the definition of $[3]_n$. $[3]_n=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}:x \equiv3 (\mod n)\}$. Notice that each element in set $\mathbb{Z}_n$ actually represents a class of integers.

You are also asking what exactly is $\mathbb{Z_n}$. By definition, $Z_n$ is set of **congruence classes** while $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers. In order words, if you want to list all the elements in $\mathbb{Z}$, there are infinitely many elements since there are infinitely many integers. However, if you want to list all the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, that is doable and there are only $n$ elements.

Comment: So the $X = \Bbb Z$, but since the operation is $\mod n$, we only get $x$ such that $x \pmod n = 3$ or whatever right?

Comment: @SalmonKiller I'm not really sure what $x (\mod n)=3$ means. I guess it's the notation that's confusing you.

Comment: I meant to write $x \mod n = 3$

Comment: @SalmonKiller So you are referring to the operation "take the remainder"? That is absolutely fine.

Comment: @SalmonKiller So you are right. The integers in $[3]_n$ are the integers such that when you divide them by $n$, the remainder is $3$. And hopefully that also explains why we can always partition all the integers into these classes.